# How to calculate results based on values from two different columns in apps script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, scripting

I'm somewhat of a beginner with Google Sheets and Apps Script and I want to know if the following is possible:

[visual description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBtRl.png)

[image]

Focusing on the weightclass and amount columns, I want to add the amount on the left to the total on the right for each weightclass. The problem with countif's as displayed in the picture is that I don't know how to incorporate the amounts into the total, only displaying how many times "FW" literally showed up in A column etc.

Any suggestions or workarounds to this? Thanks

Open to Apps Script suggestions, not sure if this is solvable inside Sheets

Comment: It can surely be done with formulas. I suggest you upload a spreadsheet and a table containing the different variables that need to be considered for making the calculations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can achieve it with this formula:

```
=sumif(G3:G7, G3, H3:H7)
```

Where `G3:G7` is the weightclasses column, `G3` is the particular class you are counting (it can be just text `"FW"`), and `H3:H7` - the amount column.